# Access VBA: How to filter a mainform by searching a subform in a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, subform

I've got a form for entering contacts which contains several subforms, many of which represent many-to-many relationships. I wish for users to be able to search contacts by values in their subforms.

Ironically, I actually have a good, functional solution for searching those subforms which represent many-to-many relationships-- usually, those are the ones that give me the most trouble! The problem is, the solution I'm using uses comboboxes, and therefore allows users to only search by the exact values available in the drop-down. Here's what I mean:

[image: The Subform in question]

```
Private Sub cboSourceSearch_AfterUpdate()

Dim strSQL As String
If IsNull(Me.cboSourceSearch) Then
    Me.Parent.RecordSource = "people"
Else
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCTROW people.* FROM people " & "INNER JOIN people_has_sourceref ON " & "people.personID = people_has_sourceref.people_personID " & "WHERE people_has_sourceref.sourceref_sourceID = " & Me.cboSourceSearch & ";"
    Me.Parent.RecordSource = strSQL
End If

End Sub
```

(Adapted from http://allenbrowne.com/ser-28.html)
Essentially this VBA is setting the RecordSource of the main form from the value in the combo-box, whose row source is the "sourceref" table-- the third in the many-to-many relationship. This works great, but what if I want to search by a note left on a contact? The table is called "Notes", and is in a many-to-one relationship with People (contacts). It's a free form block of text for entering notes relating to the contact.

I've got a general idea of how this would work, and theoretically it should be easier than the above method: Just set the RecordSource of the main form based on an SQL query which searches the Notes table with wildcard characters on either side. Yet, I can't put together a solution. This is essentially due to my lack of VBA knowledge, but I'm learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After typing this, I realized I did in fact have the VBA and SQL know-how to put together a solution, but I thought I'd post this anyway for posterity.

```
Private Sub NoteSearch_AfterUpdate()
    Dim strSQL As String
    If IsNull(Me.NoteSearch) Then
        Me.Parent.RecordSource = "people"
    Else
        strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCTROW people.* FROM people INNER JOIN notes ON people.personID = notes.people_personID WHERE notes.note LIKE '%" & Me.NoteSearch & "%'"
        Me.Parent.RecordSource = strSQL
    End If
End Sub
```

Please note: I have explicitly included the % wildcard on either side of the text in the code since I consider that to be a more common use-case than explicitly searching for a note whose exact text matches that in the search field. I suppose you could exclude the wildcard and teach the users how to include it themselves, which may be preferable.